# New count when month starts/ ends

Tags: php

I want to make a counter in php using only year, month and numbers. For example

Today's date is: 201710--- Where last 3 dash are variable. It could be any number in between 1-999.( I will add an auto increment in last 3 dash line ).

After end of October the dash line should start again from 1 for example

Example : 201711001 ....201711002....201711901.....201712001...201712010 etc

How can I do it ? Any Help ?

```
<?php 

$patid = date("Ym").$patient_count;

?>
```

Comment: Are you getting any error in the above code?

Comment: No, I am not understanding how can i set the patient_count to 001 when a month ends or starts.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve ? Do the 3 last numbers have to start from 001 and then increment ?  what sould happen if you get 201710999 before the end of October ? How this numbers should be generated: on page hit ? all at once in a loop ?

Comment: Yes 3 last number have to start from 001 and then increment when a month/year ends/starts. My numbers will never reach upto 201710999 before the end of October. I am sure about it. This numbers are patient counter.

Comment: The only way to do this is when you keep track of the last used date. So you have to store it somewhere and compare it to the new date.

Answer (score 0):

If you can keep track of the last used date and (obviously) `$patient_count`:

```
<php
//retrieve $lastdate and $patientcount (from database or file)

$newdate = date ("Ym");
if ($newdate != $lastdate) {
   $patient_count++;
   }
else {
   $patient_count = 1;
   }
$patid = $newdate.$patient_count;

$lastdate = $newdate; 
//store $lastdate and $patientcount
```